# More tables in database

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am making a gallery website. I learnt from tutorials how to do each parts but i don't know if i should make different tables for user information / their profile pictures / and photos added to gallery by users. Should I focus to make lowest number of tables possible (like putting profile pictures and photos together in table) or making different tables for everything. Does is affects speed of website?

I am using XAMPP and procedural PHP.

Comment: u can create a table with name gallery or photos and save all gallery here with userid column. normalization is better for website. for performance or speed,  you can use different ways to optimize queries and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb is always identify separate entities (things) and put them in a separate tables. Think about relations between these entities:

- Photos belong to galleries,
- Photos belong to users,
- Galleries might be owned by one or more users ect.

(These are only examples - maybe it is different in your case)

This way you will start thinking naturally using relational database concepts.

The next step is to identify what type of relation exist between these entities. And so:

- User can have many photos but a single photo is owned by single user (one to many relation or 1:n)
- User can have many galleries, and each gallery can be owned by many users (many to many relation or m:n)

Based on the above you can then create "connections" between these tables of things using so called foreign keys. Read more about simple relational database design and you'll be fine.

Regarding speed. Don't worry about it for now. The database is designed to allow us to create many different related tables of things and it is highly optimized to do so. You can worry about optimizations once you'll reach millions of items in your tables.

Comment: Maybe gallery wasn't right word. It will be more like Instagram where user will have one profile photo and more photos that will be showed on their page. I already have table for profile photos with 3 columns: id, userid, status(status is 0 or 1 depending on if they already have profile picture or not). So should photos added by them be in new table?

Comment: No I would just put all the photos in the system regardless of their use in a single table. Then for example if a user can have one profile photo, you add profile_photo_id to the user table that will hold the id of the photo from photos table. And most likely then you don't need any separate 'gallery' entity and be ok for now with Users and Photos tables.

Answer (score 0):

i think You Are beginner So you  may learn more from here

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8Nbgc4vUi27HgBv2ffEiHw